# React Native Project error : ld: framework not found GoogleAdMob

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I face this issue when try to build the app for production. But I could build the app in simulator. I face this issue and also solved it

Answer (score 0):

Need to update cocoa pods to the latest version
run: pod install

Answer (score 0):

Use this command which will remove existing pods and install pod again. This will also remove node_modules and do a fresh install.

```
rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install && cd ..
```